# Why can I not navigate to URL in Flutter when variable is used?

Tags: ios, flutter, google-maps, dart, url

I have two almost identical functions:

```
  void _launchGoogleMapsURL() async {
    var GoogleMapsLongLat = widget.place!.location!.LongLatforGoogleMaps()!;
    var url ="https://maps.google.com?q=${GoogleMapsLongLat}"; // DOES NOT WORK
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    }
  }
```

And:

```
  void _actionViewMoreArticles() async {
    var url = "https://mywebsitename.com/plainurl"; // WORKS!
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    }
  }
```

And the button:

```
                CupertinoButton(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                      child: Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 0, left: 20),
                            child: Text(
                              Localized.of(context)!.trans(LocalizedKey.navigate) ?? "",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontFamily: TraloFont,
                                  fontSize: 16,
                                  color: Colors.white),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      onPressed: _launchGoogleMapsURL,
                    ),
```

So, if I try to open Google Maps with the long/lat, it does not work (Xcode does not give me any error when tested on my real device), but when I use a 'plain URL' like shown in the example, it does work.

Lastly, here is how the function looks like:

```
extension longLatforGoogle on String { 
  LongLatforGoogleMaps (){
    var latAndLng = this.split(",").map((text) => double.tryParse(text));
    if (latAndLng.length == 2) {
      return latAndLng;
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:**

This is what the console says:

```
component name for https://maps.google.com?q=(52.366722, 4.889386) is null
```

I get the same error with the 'plain URL', but that one actually opens the page and it works.

If I print GoogleMapsLongLat, I get:

```
(52.366722, 4.889386)
```

If I only use await launch(url) in Xcode, it gives me the following error:

```
terminating app due to uncaught exception 'nsinvalidargumentexception'
```

and as reason: `the specified URL has an unsupported scheme. Only HTTP and HTTP urls are supported.`

But that's weird, because I am using HTTPS as you can see.

Comment: And what is the `String` representation for the value of `GoogleMapsLongLat`?  Have you checked what URL you're actually trying to open?  Currently you're doing an apples-to-oranges comparison where you're using two completely different URLs.

Comment: Please print `GoogleMapsLongLat` and share the value.

Comment: See my edited question (last part) for the answer on your questions.

Comment: Can you clarify what "does not work" means?  Does nothing happen?  Have you checked which of `canLaunch(url)` and `launch(url)` is failing?  What does `await canLaunch('https://maps.google.com?q=(52.366722, 4.889386)')` return?  What about `await canLaunch('https://maps.google.com/?q=(52.366722,4.889386)'` (note no space)?

Comment: When I do those, I get the same result in the console. Nothing changes. If I remove canLaunch and just use await launch(url), it opens the Google Maps in the simulator. When I try this in Xcode (real device), the screen freezes and pushes me out the app. Surely I must be doing something wrong?

The error in the console is: terminating app due to uncaught exception 'nsinvalidargumentexception' . See the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it myself. Thanks for the nudge.

I did this:

```
var NoWhiteSpaceURL = Googleurl.replaceAll(' ', '');
if (await canLaunch(NoWhiteSpaceURL)) {
  await launch(NoWhiteSpaceURL);
}
```

The problem occurs (apparently), when there is a whitespace in the URL. That is why it is giving those errors. Removing them has solved the issue for me.